# read.table() from URL with required authorization in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rcurl, read.table

I am trying to read a table from a URL without downloading the file first. The URL points to a .txt-file which needs authorization for access.

As I see it, read.table() offers no authorization option for URLs. So I tried with getURL() respectively getURLContent(). Authorization works well and I'm able to download the content of the .txt as a big string. The data is whitespace delimited and the each row is completed with a \n. 
But I failed to separate the data from the string.

A short extract:

```
2012      25     494624.00    515578.00   1010202.00\n2012      26     481741.00    501734.00    983475.00\n2012      27     482058.00    501814.00    983872.00\n2012      28     487687.00    505376.00    993063.00\n2012      29     500999.00    518991.00   1019990.00\n2012      30     501696.00    514919.00   1016615.00\n2012      31     505979.00    519961.00   1025940.00\n2012      32     481919.00    495490.00    977409.00\n2012      33     475873.00    489363.00    965236.00\n2012      34     472357.00    485357.00    957714.00\n2012      35     466101.00    478564.00    944665.00\n
```

So is there a nice way to get a data.frame out of this data? The question is not how get a data.frame out of the string - I could figure that out myself. The question is if it's possible to use sth like read.table for this.

Sadly I can't share my access secret to the .txt-file, so I am happy with useful hints.

Answer (score 0):

Bring in your string

```
mystring <- "2012      25     494624.00    515578.00   1010202.00\n2012      26     481741.00    501734.00    983475.00\n2012      27     482058.00    501814.00    983872.00\n2012      28     487687.00    505376.00    993063.00\n2012      29     500999.00    518991.00   1019990.00\n2012      30     501696.00    514919.00   1016615.00\n2012      31     505979.00    519961.00   1025940.00\n2012      32     481919.00    495490.00    977409.00\n2012      33     475873.00    489363.00    965236.00\n2012      34     472357.00    485357.00    957714.00\n2012      35     466101.00    478564.00    944665.00\n"
```

split your string using "\n

```
mystring <- strsplit(mystring, split= "\n")
```

create list with counter, loop through your string to sub out multiple spaces for single space, and split each row into columns by space delimiter

```
allstring <- list()  
count <- 1 
for (i in 1:length(mystring[[1]])){
a<- gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", mystring[[1]][i], perl = TRUE)  
b <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(a, " ")) 
allstring[[count]] <-b    
count <- count + 1
}
```

convert list to data.frame

```
allstring.df<- do.call(rbind.data.frame, allstring)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, definitely helpful. But that was not the question actually. Please note my edits.